# Subquery formation for predicates along with group By

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, subquery

Consider the following `Books` table in Postgres.
[image]

Wanted to write a query that should do the following:

1. for each grouping based on `type` (fiction/horror) find out the **average price for each category** of `type`.
2. Display all the books that have **price higher than average** - **for that type(horror/fiction)**.

Was wandering how **can this be done using the subquery** - wherein I can get the result(2nd) based on the compute(1st).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**1)average price for each category**

```
Select type, AVG(price) From books group by type
```

**2) price higher than average**

```
select b1.type, b1.price, b1.ID 
From books b1
Where b1.price > (
                  Select AVG(b.price)
                  From books b
                   Where b.type = b1.type
                 )
```